# Strange zero initialization with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I came across on a strange behavior of the following code, while playing around with initialization of ints using g++ 4.4.3.

```
  int main()

    {

        int x(int());

        int y = int();

        cout << x << "  " << y <<  endl;
    }
```

the result is:

1 0

The value of "y" is 0 as expected, but the value of x is strangely "1"!

On VS2008 yields the following link error (a function declaration, but without definition):

```
unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl x(int (__cdecl*)(void))"
```

Can anyone explain this strange behavior of g++?

Comment: @Skavcho, good question. `x` is interpreted as function declaration. You can try rather `int x(*new int());`. It will give you expected result as 0 0.

Comment: @iammilind: Yes but it will leak.

Comment: @Benoit: Yes, every time `main()` is called...

Comment: @Ben Jackson: don't belittle Benoit's answer so simply. This code snippet is only a code example, meant to have the smallest executive program possible. However the answer to the question will be used in the midst of real code. So **yes** it's important NOT to leak.

Comment: As @Jan said - this would do the job: int x((int()));

Comment: Adding up to @Matthieu M. comment above: even if it is only one int, it is still important not to leak.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To complement GMan's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815236/strange-zero-initialization-with-g/5815263#5815263) (`x` is a function definition) as to why the `1`.

The reason for the output to be `1` is that at the place of call `std::cout << x`, the function decays into a pointer to the function (the language does not allow you to pass functions as arguments to other functions, so as with arrays an implicit conversion to *pointer-to* is performed). Now, there is no overload of an `ostream` that takes a function pointer, and the compiler tries to select a conversion to any of the available overloads. At that point it finds that the *best* conversion sequence is to `bool` and it prints `1` (the pointer is not 0).

You can check this by changing the behavior, you can use `std::cout << std::boolalpha << x`, and that will print `true` instead of `1`. Also, it is interesting to note that VS is right with this one, as the expression `std::cout << x` requires taking the address of `x`, then the function is *used* and the program is ill-formed if there is no definition for that function. You can again check that by providing a definition:

```
int f() {}
int main() {
   int x(int());      // 1
   x( &f );           // 2
}
int x( int(*)() ) {   // 3
   std::cout << "In x" << std::endl;
}
```

Where I have manually performed the conversion from `function` to `pointer-to-function` in the definition of `x` (1) and the call with the argument `f` (2) --note that the declaration in 1 and the definition in 3 *are* the same signature, and that the `&` in `x( &f )` will be performed by the compiler if you don't do it.

Answer (score 24):

`int x(int());` is parsed as function declaration.

It declares a function named `x`, returning an `int` and accepting one parameter, which has the type of a function returning an `int` and accepting no arguments.

This is known as the most vexing parse.

Comment: And why "its value" (not the quotes ) is 1 ? Isn't it supposed to be a address of a function of something? (+1, btw)

Comment: Most vexing parse?  No love for misinterpretation of `X<Y<Z>>`?

Comment: @Ben - I'd agree with GMan, as `X<Y<Z>>` is pretty obvious and (already) well-known, while this declaration of function is not that "familiar"

Comment: Doh! It's an declaration, not definition, that's why it's not an address. But still - why it's `1`

Comment: It's 1 because:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout

Comment: @Ben, others: [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Meyers) first pubished in 1992 by Scott Meyers. (all of C++ parsing is mildly vexing, but there can only be one Ivan The Terrible too)

Comment: Uhm... darn, I have just written a long answer to the `1` just to realize that that had been asked before.

Answer (score 4):

Just add more parens:

```
int main()

    {

        int x((int()));

        int y = int();

        cout << x << "  " << y <<  endl;
    }
```

Now x is an int, not a function.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, `x` is a function declaration.  Since there is no predefined ostream inserter defined for function pointer types, g++ appears to using the implicit bool conversion (used for checking if a function pointer is NULL) to find a way to output it.

Visual C++, on the other hand, is complaining that the declared function `x` is never defined, and thus it can't complete the link.  I suspect g++ in this case is smart enough to see that the function is never called, and thus doesn't worry about the link.

You might try adding a dummy definition of the function `int x(int(*)()) { return 0xdeadbeef; }` to the code and see what MSVC does with it then.

Answer (score 2):

C++ interprets the first one as the declaration of a function.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
int x(int());
```

Is actually a function declaration the input is a function of following signature

```
int fn(void)
```

The function pointer passed to `std::cout <<`  is converted to a bool(1) as it is a non-NULL pointer.