# difference between function pointers in c and c++

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print function pointers with cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout)

What is the difference between function pointers in c and c++? When I'm printing function pointer in c++ it's giving 1, but in c it's giving an address.

```
#include <iostream>

int fun()
{}

typedef int (*f)();


int main()
{
    f test = fun;
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<f>(test);
}


#include <stdio.h>

int fun()
{}

int (*f)();

int main()
{
    f = fun;
    printf("%p", f);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by f test = fun in your c++ code, I guess it wont even compile

Comment: @niko - try it, it does.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<f>(test);` Hug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function pointer can't convert to `void*`, so in program using C++ i/o it converts to `bool`. The C program is also a C++ program. You should get no difference when you compile it as C++.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is the printing mechanism you're using. std::cout and printf have different semantics. std::cout refers to your pointer as boolean data and prints either 0 or 1 instead of the address.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is what's the difference between printf with "%p" and cout when you stream a pointer to a function.

To print out the pointer to function in C++, try casting it to a char* and iterating through the bytes (with length of sizeof(test)).  I think you'll find it to be similar to "%p"

Comment: +1 clever: I was just trying to think how to get around the problem with function pointers (method) potentially not fitting into a standard pointer.