# c++ static method output using cout is always 1

Tags: c++, methods, static

So i have a piece of code with a class like that:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

class stu
{
    static int proba;
public:
    stu();
    static int no(){
        return proba;
    }
};

int stu::proba=0;

stu::stu()
{
    proba=proba+1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<< stu::no << std::endl;
}
```

The output is 1.
It does so even if i change `stu::no` so that it would be only `{return 12;}`
Why does it happen? How do I fix it??

Comment: is this is a typo because stu::no is a function and it should print something that looks like a pointer. Did you mean std::cout << stu::no() << std::endl; ?

Answer (score 7):

Change it to `std::cout<< stu::no() << std::endl;`

Without the `()`, I believe it's evaluating as a pointer, and not doing what you're expecting.

Edit:  As pointed out by @Loomchild, using `g++ -Wall` will provide further insight as to why it's always 1.  The pointer to the static function is always evaluated as `true` in this context, hence the value being printed.

Comment: `g++ -Wall` warns with the following : `warning: the address of 'static int stu::no()' will always evaluate as 'true'`

Comment: @Loomchild:  Ah, that explains it.

Comment: Oh, i can see that, could you give me any hint how i could do that without additional "()", i mean without changing main ?

Comment: @user1267757: Not really.  If you want `main()` to call a function, you have to use the function call syntax, which involves putting the () after the function name.  Any workaround would still involve a change to main to make it call a function.

Comment: oh, i got it now, i just changed name of "proba" into "no" and then deleted former "no"

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout<< stu::no << std::endl;` prints the address of the function, you're not actually calling it.

```
std::cout<< stu::no() << std::endl;
```

calls the function and prints the return value.

In MSVS, this indeed produces a pointer value, with the overload `operator << (void*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use stu::no() instead of stu::no.
Also, a minor thing really but if you put

using namespace std;

below the #includes you won't have to use std::

Just makes things a little more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`stu::no` is a function that takes no arguments and returns int.

There is no `operator<<` that takes functions with your particular signature, so the available overloads are considered. Long story short, the `operator<<(ostream&, bool)` is the closest match, after function-to-pointer and pointer-to-bool conversions.

Since the function actually exists, its address is definitely non-zero, so the pointer to bool conversion always yields `true`, which you see as `1`.

Make it `std::cout<< std::boolalpha << stu::no << std::endl;` to see for yourself that it's really a boolean output.

Make it `std::cout<< stu::no() << std::endl;` to print the result of the function call.

See [How to print function pointers with cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout) if you want to know what happened in more detail.