# g++ "calling" a function without parenthesis (not f() but f; ). Why does it always return 1?

Tags: c++, g++

In c++ (GNU GCC g++), my code is "calling" a function without ().
The function is not working, but compiles ok.

More surprisingly, the code always returns 1...

Is there any explanation?

I expected the function name to be just a regular pointer, but seems it's a bit different...

Did I get all 1's only by chance?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void pr ()
{
    cout << "sth";
}

int main()
{

pr;
cout << pr;  // output: 1
cout << *pr; // output: 1
cout << &pr; // output: 1

}
```

Comment: Implicit cast to bool of a function address.

Comment: This post may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout

Comment: Implicit **conversion** to bool of a function address. There is no such thing as in implicit cast.

Comment: Leave it to the C++ questions to attract the pedants `:P`

Comment: Also: turn on your compiler's warnings to catch this sort of stuff. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c5a9325689a325174aba61a645cedd2e-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Answer (score 20):

You're not actually calling `pr` in your code, you're passing the function pointer to `cout`.  `pr` is then being converted to a `bool` when being passed to `cout`.  If you put `cout << boolalpha` beforehand you will output `true` instead of `1`.

**EDIT:**
With C++11 you can write the following overload:

```
    template <class RType, class ... ArgTypes>
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & s, RType(*func)(ArgTypes...))
    {
        return s << "(func_ptr=" << (void*)func << ")(num_args=" 
                 << sizeof...(ArgTypes) << ")";
    }
```

which means the call `cout << pr` will print `(func_ptr=<address of pr>)(num_args=0)`.  The function itself can do whatever you want obviously, this is just to demonstrate that with C++11's variadic templates, you can match function pointers of arbitrary arity.  This still won't work for overloaded functions and function templates without specifying which overload you want (usually via a cast).

Comment: And that's a fallacy in the typesafe C++ iostreams. Or rather, in the implicit conversions of C++.

Comment: @rubenvb Check the edit, with C++11 there's a cure for that now.

Comment: note that `(void *)func` is a *conditionally-supported* feature, the compiler may reject it

Answer (score 5):

The name of a function, when used without parentheses, can be implicitly cast to a function pointer. In fact, when you dereference or reference it, it remains nothing but a function pointer, or a poointer to a function pointer, etc. These function pointers, when printed, are implicitly cast to `bool`, which is why they simply output 1. If you want to output the actual memory address of the function, cast it to a void pointer:

```
cout<<(void*)pr;
```

Comment: More generally, in most contexts, an expression of function type (including a function name) is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function. Exceptions are when it's the argument to `sizeof` (which is illegal) or to unary `&` (which yields the address of the function). This applies even when the function name is followed by parentheses; a function call requires a pointer-to-function as its first operand.

Comment: BTW, casting a function pointer to `void*` is likely to work on most systems, but I don't believe the behavior is defined. (For example, the conversion could lose information if function pointers are bigger than `void*`.)

Comment: Is there a `(void*)pr` equivalent that is well-formed?  Some sort of `(void_fnptr_t*)pr`?