# C++ function call without brackets

Tags: c++

I came across this while programming and forgetting the brackets after the function call, but I only got a warning, which I overlooked:

```
main.cpp:7:15: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
                if (i == 0) clearDisplay;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The same thing happens when just doing

```
int i = 0;
i;
```

Why isn't this a compiler error?

```
#include <iostream>

void clearDisplay(void);

int main(void){
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if (i == 0) clearDisplay;
    }
}

void clearDisplay(void){
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
```

EDIT:
As opposed to [g++ "Calling" function without parenthesis ( not f() but f; ). Why always returns 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073066/g-calling-function-without-parenthesis-not-f-but-f-why-always-return) I don't ask why it is implicitly casted to a number but why the compiler doesn't warn me about that like it does with `if(i=0)` to `if(i==0)`

Comment: It's not clear what misunderstanding needs to be corrected here. Why do you think that should be a compiler error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073066/g-calling-function-without-parenthesis-not-f-but-f-why-always-return

Comment: What is the problem with omitting the brackets? Or is that part just incidental?

Comment: @joel-cornett accidental

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can regard `clearDisplay` as the address of the function. Crucually, it will have a non-zero numerical value, and a statement consisting of a single variable is grammatically correct.

Comment: Why can I say `i;` and it is correct? It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: `i;` compiles too so long as `i` has been declared.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same reason this is not a compiler error:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
```

Look at `i++`. That's an expression whose result you've completely ignored. But that's perfectly legal. Why? Because you are allowed to ignore the results of expressions.

To be helpful, your compiler warns you when you ignore the results of expressions with no side-effects. But if there was a language rule that it was illegal to ignore expressions with no side-effects, that would require compilers to perfectly tell whether expressions have side-effects or not, and that's basically impossible.

Comment: `i++` is the same as `i = i +1;` so it isn't ignored because it changes the value of i

Comment: No, the value of the *expression* `i++` is being ignored.

Comment: @mischnic In `i = i + 1;`, the result *is* ignored. You could have said `printf("%d", i = i + 1);` but instead you ignored the result of assigning a new value to `i`. (Because all you wanted was the side-effect of evaluating the expression, which was an assignment. You didn't care about the value, so you ignored it.)

Comment: Oh, but `i++;` does something compared to `i;`. And `i = i + 1` actually returns `i+1`, sets the new value and returns the new value.

Comment: Exactly. So C++ has to let you ignore the results of expressions. We often ignore the results of expressions when what we want are the side-effects of evaluating the expression. But, to be nice, compilers should warn you when they see you ignoring the results of expressions they know have no side-effects, since that appears pointless.

Comment: @mischnic a similar usage is calling a function and ignore the return value

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc but that actually does something

Comment: No, the thing here is `expression;` is a valid statement in C and C++. Regardless of the side effects of the expression, you're discarding the result. `i = i + 1` **is** an expression because it returns a value and you can use it in subsequent expression like `if (i = i + 1)` or `j = i = i + 1`...

Comment: @mischnic Do you think the compiler can always tell whether an expression has side-effects or not? (Consider `abs(c);` versus `putc(c);`). If not, how could you have a rule that ignoring the results of an expression is only allowed if the evaluation has side-effects.

Comment: operator++ is a function without using parenthese<b>()</b>, but this is nature of function call of various operators. A function call should have <b>()</b> to distinguish itself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nutshell explanation.

In the same way that this expression:

```
i;
```

is just referring to the variable `i` without actually doing anything with it, this expression:

```
clearDisplay;
```

simply refers to the `clearDisplay` function without actually calling it.

Comment: Why can I refer to `i` without doing anything?

Comment: @mischnic I don't know. I would say it's just another flaw with C++. Other languages like Java don't allow you to do that.

Comment: Yeah, usually I use java and thats why I stumbled across this.

Comment: Don't forget that some compilers actually produce code when you do this. Try e.g. with gcc (4.8) when `i` is volatile, where you get actual code to load the value of `i` (clang doesn't but warns about the issue).