# Why do C library functions seem present in any C++ code as pointers to functions?

Tags: c++

I came to this conclusion when I was trying to figure out what was going on with the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << (div) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

`div` above could be substituted with `printf`, `atoi`, `difftime`, etc. Whether or not I was `#include`ing the appropriate headers (`ctime`, `time.h`, `cstdlib`, ..., ), I was getting no compiler errors and the program was printing `1`. Program was not compiling when I was prefixing the function name with `std::`.

`Clang`'s warnings explained what was going on:

```
warning: address of function 'div' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Wbool-conversion]
```

So my questions are:

- Why do names of C library function have any meaning even when the appropriate headers are not `#include`d?
- Why are they defined as pointers to functions?
- Why do they reside outside namespace `std`?

Comment: Are you sure that `<iostream>` is your only include? Headers can and do often include other headers which would explain that you see this functions as declared. However, I doubt that `<iostream>` includes all the examples you mention

Comment: With regard to your first question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17073066/1538531

Comment: Doesn't work on MSVC2015 or MinGW-GCC-5. @tobi303 I doubt it too now

Comment: "C" functions are not "defined as pointers to functions" it's just that when you specify just the name of the function the "C" standard has declared that to mean the address of the function, that is, "div == &div". I don't like it either, but that's the way it is. And since "C++" is based on the "C" standard, that same meaning has carried over.

Comment: @tobi303 , http://ideone.com/iSitZQ - yes I'm sure iostream is my only include

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Not sure if I understand you correctly. Does the C standard declare that the name of a function is equivalent to the address of the function? If so, what does e.g. `printf("%d",10)` mean? `0x00ff88dd33("%d",10)`? Doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @gaazkam, yes, that is right the C standard does declare that. So yes,`printf("%d", 10)` is equivalent to a properly casted `0x00ff88dd33("%d",10)`

Answer (score 4):

- Standard library headers are allowed to include other headers without advertising the fact.
- These are functions, and their names decay to pointer to function
- Because the standard unfortunately allows to import names from the C library into the global namespace even if these are defined in one of the `<cxxx>` headers.

Comment: Nice. But in this case, why does prepending `std::` to the name of the function cause compilation error? Like in `std::cout << std::div`? Why doesn't `std::div` decay to pointer to function?

Comment: @gaazkam It should, decay but maybe that name hasn't been introduced by the include. It could be that the implementation is non-conforming.

Comment: `#include <cstdlib>` (...) `std::cout << (std::div) << '\n';` gives out kilometre-long compilation errors: http://ideone.com/BT8rbL Having looked at them a little more carefully, it seems that `std::div` does decay, only the compiler doesn't know the adress of which overload it should use.

Comment: @gaazkam That makes sense, there are a few overloads: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
//#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int j =  (div) ;
  return 0;
}
```

It fails to compile. Somewhere in iostream it is including stdlib.h which defines div into the global namespace

div is a function in your code. Which c++ ends up implicitly converting to a true bool