# How does the compiler determine what value to output during runtime when a function name is sent to cout without parenthesis? C++

Tags: c++, function, iostream, std

```
#include <iostream>

int returnFive()
{
   return 5;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << returnFive << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Since this compiles without error, how does the system determine what value is actually sent and printed to console?

Comment: See [How to print function pointers with cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout). There is no "*function call*" involved in the posted code.

Comment: The error produced by g++ is quite informative: https://godbolt.org/z/aePP3c

Comment: To call a function in C++ you *must* use parentheses. Otherwise (without parentheses) the function decays to a *pointer* to the function, i.e. `&returnFive`.

Comment: you may find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073066/g-calling-a-function-without-parenthesis-not-f-but-f-why-does-it-alwa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [g++ "calling" a function without parenthesis (not f() but f; ). Why does it always return 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073066/g-calling-a-function-without-parenthesis-not-f-but-f-why-does-it-alwa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine if the code written is something like

```
if(returnFive)
  returnFive();
```

Here the expectation is that the compiler checks if the function pointer for `returnFive` is `nullptr` or not.

The compiler here is evaluating the function pointer as a boolean expression of whether it is NULL or not and printing the output.

https://godbolt.org/z/Psdc69. You can check that the `cout` is being passed a `(bool)`.