# C++ programming riddle, fun with function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Given the following code snippet:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string prefix("->"), middle(), suffix("<-");
    std::cout << "Test: " << prefix << middle << suffix << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The advanced C++ programmer will immediately see that `middle()` is not calling `std::string`'s default ctor, instead it's a function declaration.

What's interesting though: Why does gcc produce the following output:

```
Test: ->1<-
```

in contrast to Visual Studio's linker error? Does anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: I've got a downvote and a close request for this question (off-topic), can anybody maybe tell me why. Is such a question really off-topic on SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function pointer will be converted to `bool` when using with `cout`.

Why the function pointer is not converted to a `void *` implicitly, which is what operator << overloads on? because function pointers are not object pointers.

C++11 §4.10/2:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T,” where T is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv void”. The result of converting a “pointer to cv T” to a “pointer to cv void” points to the start of the storage location where the object of type T resides, as if the object is a most derived object (1.8) of type T (that is, not a base class subobject). The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.

Comment: Thanks, I was guessing something like that. Do you know by chance why VS produces a linker error instead? Which behavior is "standard" and which is "wrong"?

Comment: @D.R.: I think your program has undefined behavior, so both are "correct".  Here's the rule: "Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program; **no diagnostic required**."

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout

Comment: BenVoigt's comment actually answers the question. The question is not "why my function is being printed as `1`", but "why is it not producing a linker error on gcc".

Answer (score 1):

As Yu said, the function pointer is being converted to `bool`.

The g++ optimizer is evidently pre-evaluating the conversion, while Visual C++ actually generates code to test if the function address is null, which requires the linker to provide the function address.

The rule is that

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic required.

The function *is* odr-used because you're using its address.  By not providing a definition, you're violating this rule, and the Standard doesn't require a diagnostic, meaning the toolchain is free to do anything it wants.

Visual C++ is generating a diagnostic, although it's not required to.

g++ is giving the actual result of conversion to `bool`, since it knows that decay of an actual function to a function pointer can never produce a null function pointer.

But formatting your hard drive would be equally valid, since the Standard doesn't say what the toolchain can or can't do here.