# Printing the address of member function

Tags: c++, function, member

```
struct Widget {
    void test() {}
};

int func() {}

int main() {
    std::cout << &Widget::test << std::endl;
    std::cout << Widget::test << std::endl;
    std::cout << func << std::endl;
    std::cout << &func << std::endl;
}
```

In this code only the second line of main function doesn't compile. The others print `1`. Why does it print `1`. Shouldn't print the address of function? And why second doesn't compile but first does?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it print 1. Shouldn't print the address of function?

No. `std::cout` can print a `void*`, but there's no implicit conversion from function pointer types to `void*` (for neither regular function pointers nor pointer-to-member types). There's a conversion from function pointer types to `bool` though. That's what we end up with.

> And why second doesn't compile but first does?

Because the standard requires you to use `&` to get the address of a member function.