# Why the pointer of any function always shows one?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, stack-trace, function-calls

I am trying to do something like

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo () {
  void (*fooptr) (void) = foo;
  cout << fooptr << endl;
}

int main () {
  void (*fooptr) (void) = foo;
  foo ();
  return 0;
}
```

My intent is to see the value of function pointers. If I look up for the address of any function in the `main ()` function it makes sense that the function isn't called, It might have not been allocated the memory in the function call stack. But when I call the function and try to see the value of pointer. It still shows the same result `1`. Any explanation?
I might not be printing the address of the called function itself. Is there any pointer like `this` like we have in classes. So that we can see the address of itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064692/395718

Comment: tl;dr : cast `fooptr` to `void*`. If it doesn't work then tough luck...

Comment: A function pointer is not a pointer to the stack frame the function call is using, is a pointer to the code of the function

Comment: You are converting (int)(bool)fooo implecetely :)

Comment: Why the value is one? I dont know, but that the value is always the same makes sense: As I said, is just the location of the function code

Comment: @Manu343726 means they are logical addresses?

Comment: Yes they are the address where the code of the function starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard stream types don't overload `<<` for function pointers, only for regular pointers. You see the value 1 because a function pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool`, and there is an overload for `bool`, so that is chosen.

To print the address, you could convert it to a regular (object) pointer:

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(fooptr) << std::endl;
```

Note that this isn't completely portable: according to the standard, it's conditionally-supported, with an implementation-defined meaning. But it should give the expected address on any sensible implementation on mainstream platforms that store functions in regular memory. For more portability, you might convert to `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`; but you'd need a bit of extra work if you want it to be formatted like a pointer.

Comment: Why the conversion from function pointers to bool is defined? What is its purpose?

Comment: @Manu343726: As with a regular pointer, it converts to `false` if null, `true` otherwise, so you can write e.g. `if (fooptr) fooptr();`.