# Initialize function pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, function-pointers

I have the following code and to my surprise it works.

```
int func()
{
    cout << "aep" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int sp;
    int (*k)() = *****func;
    k();
    return 0;
}
```

Аs far as I know, functions pointer can be initialized in two ways

```
1.int (*k)() = func
2.int (*k)() = &func
```

But what happens in case of ?

```
int (*k)() = *func or int (*k)() = ***func ?
```

And one more thing, `cout << func` gets as a result **1**, why ?

Comment: Here is a duplicate for the "one more thing" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It [works](http://ideone.com/AAq6Gj) once you fix missing `std::`.