# Why function pointer address is printing in bool type in c++?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, iostream, cout

The following code outputs `1`, but I expect it to output the address of the function `add`. What is going wrong?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

int main()
{
    int (*func_ptr)(int,int) = add;
    std::cout << "The address of function add() is: " << func_ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The function pointer is implicitly cast to boolean.  There was a similar question recently,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print function pointers with cout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Function pointers aren't convertible to data pointers. You'd get a compiler error if you were to try and assign one to a `void*` variable. But they are implicitly convertible to `bool`!

That is why the `bool` overload for `operator<<` is chosen over the `const void*` one.

To force the overload you want, you'd need to use a very strong C++ cast, that will *almost* completely ignore the static type information.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

int main()
{
    int (*func_ptr)(int,int) = add;
    std::cout << "The address of function add() is: "
              << reinterpret_cast<void*>(func_ptr)
              << std::endl;
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Kn8bse8K3)*

Note that casting and treating function pointers as data pointers is only conditionally supported (from the C++ standard standpoint). Using it for anything other than casting back to the same function pointer will have an implementation specific outcome, that can very greatly among compilers.

Answer (score 3):

The overload used is

```
ostream& ostream::operator<< (bool val);
```

Which prints `1` as your function pointer is not null.