# Initialization of static bool with lambda and constexpr-if gives adress error

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, if-constexpr

I was trying to implement a certain type trait, but faced this following error.

Here is a simple program that shows the behavior:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct my_floating_point // just to make a case
{
    // static constexpr bool value = std::is_floating_point_v<T>;
    // THIS WORKS

    static constexpr bool value = []()
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_floating_point_v<T>) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }; // compilation error
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << my_floating_point<int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_floating_point<double>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_floating_point<char>::value << std::endl;
}
```

The commented line works just fine.
However, the uncommented piece of code gives this warning with `g++`:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 main.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr const bool my_floating_point<int>::value’:
main.cpp:18:39:   required from here
main.cpp:9:24: warning: the address of ‘static constexpr bool my_floating_point<int>::<lambda()>::_FUN()’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
  static constexpr bool value = []()
                        ^~~~~
main.cpp:9:24: warning: the address of ‘static constexpr bool my_floating_point<int>::<lambda()>::_FUN()’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
```

And running it outputs

```
1
1
1
```

What is wrong?

**Note:** `clang++` for some reason doesn't give warning, but outputs the same.

Comment: You don't invoke the lambda.`[](){ ... }()` ought to do it. The fact it compiles at all is due to the same reason [a lambda may be streamable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002990/why-is-this-lambda-streamable).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica implicit conversion of stateless lambda to bool...  I'm gradually coming over to the side of people who say that shouldn't be a thing :)

Comment: @M.M - Welcome aboard :)

Comment: That actually works, thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 []()
    {
      // ...
    }
```

A lambda expression evaluates to an instance of an anonymous type. That's what a lambda really is: an object whose type is unspecified. Attempting to assign an instance of this object to a `bool` is not valid C++.

The good news is that this anonymous type has an `operator()` overload, that just happens, accidentally, to return a bool. So, for example, this will work:

```
static constexpr bool value = []()
{
    if constexpr(std::is_floating_point_v<T>) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}(); // compiles just fine.
```

Comment: It is valid code because stateless lambda implicitly converts to pointer to free function, which implicitly converts to bool (with value `true`). The OP compiler is being good QoI in warning that this is probably not what was intended

Answer (score 3):

***Summary:** Simplify to get a more readable warning message, then compare the message to a possibly better-recognized case. This is more of a work-through answer (teach to fish) than a direct explanation (give a fish).*

---

This is one of the cases where really working at a *minimal* [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can have benefits. I acknowledge that some of the complication was kept "just to make a case", but let's drop that for now.

The three lines in `main` each trigger the same warning, so simplify to just one of those lines. Preferably, we keep a line whose output is unexpected, such as the first of the three lines (`int` is not a floating point type, so `my_floating_point<int>::value` is intended to be false). That cuts the compiler's messages to a third of what they were and helps identify which messages go together (at this point, they all go together).

With only one type to consider, we no longer need to `my_floating_point` to be a template. Templates sometimes add a significant amount of insignificant detail to warnings (such as – *in this case* – the `required from here` message), so drop the template and replace `std::is_floating_point_v<T>` with `std::is_floating_point_v<int>`. This reduces the warning down to one message plus the indication of where the warning occurred.

One more simplification: take `value` outside the `struct`, allowing `my_floating_point` to be eliminated. Admittedly, this does not have much impact on the error message, but it does remove a red herring from the example code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

static constexpr bool value = []()
{
    if constexpr(std::is_floating_point_v<int>) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}; // compilation warning

int main()
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

```
prog.cc:7:1: warning: the address of 'static constexpr bool<lambda()>::_FUN()' will never be NULL [-Waddress]
    7 | }; // compilation warning
      | ^
```

Note that this is almost one of the lines from the question's compiler output. The only difference is the removal of `my_floating_point<int>::` which corresponds nicely with the simplifications we did.

---

OK, now that we have the situation suitably simplified, let's compare the warning to one produced in a slightly different setup. Instead of a lambda, let's use an official function. The goal is to gain some basic (yet imprecise) understanding by by comparing similar scenarios.

*Don't get hung up on "how would I think to do this?" This is something I knew to do because I recalled a remarkably similar warning from a different setup. The first part of this answer presented steps that I think are reasonable to expect from others. In contrast, this part of this answer requires familiarity with messages from the compiler.*

```cpp
#include <iostream>

bool fun()
{
    if constexpr(std::is_floating_point_v<int>) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}

static constexpr bool value = fun; // compilation warning

int main()
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

```
prog.cc:9:31: warning: the address of 'bool fun()' will never be NULL [-Waddress]
    9 | static constexpr bool value = fun; // compilation warning
      |                               ^~~
```

Again, the same warning that the address of [something] will never be NULL. (Perhaps you already see where this is going?) In this code, since the function is not invoked, the symbol `fun` becomes a pointer to the function. Assigning a pointer to a `bool` results in `true` if and only if the pointer is non-null. This particular pointer cannot be null because it is the address of something. So the compiler throws out a warning; the code is syntactically valid, but you probably meant to invoke the function (by adding parentheses just before the semicolon, as in `fun()` instead of just `fun`).

Similar mechanics are in play for the code with a lambda. When the lambda is not invoked, it can convert to a `bool`, becoming `true` if and only if there is a lambda. As in the function case, the result has to be `true`. The compiler throws out a warning; the code is syntactically valid, but you probably meant to invoke the lambda (by adding parentheses just before the semicolon).

```cpp
static constexpr bool value = []()
{
    if constexpr(std::is_floating_point_v<int>) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}(); // no compilation warning with the parentheses
```

Even better, the output is now `0`, as intended.

---

OK, the short version is "add parentheses", but the real lesson of this answer is the usefulness of recognizing compiler messages. When a warning is worded similarly to one you've encountered before, try to replicate the warning you are familiar with. See if there are similarities that allow you to transfer a solution from the familiar case to the less familiar one.

Familiarity takes time, but it takes less time if you make it a goal. ;)

Comment: For those who really want to simplify: the lambda could be reduced to `[]() { return false; }`. However, that would make this answer even longer, and I don't see enough benefit to justify that. (The warning does not change.)

Comment: Nice technique! I always get confused after some time by the compiler messages.. Thanks!