# Printing function pointer passed as a parameter results in '1' printed on the screen

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I've been experimenting with function pointers and found the behavior of the following program rather misterious:

```
void foo(int(*p)())
{ std::cout << p << std::endl; }

int alwaysReturns6()
{ return 6; }

int main()
{
    foo(alwaysReturns6);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints the number '1' on the screen.

I know I should access the function pointer like this: `p()` (and then 6 gets printed), but I still don't get what the plain `p` or `*p` means when used in the `foo` function.

Comment: `cout` always prints function pointers as `1` unless they are null. That's because its `<<` has no special overload for them, and closest overload (the one you get) is for `bool`. Cast the pointer to something like `uintptr_t` to see its real value.

Answer (score 6):

```
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

here an [overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) of `operator<<` which accepts a `bool` is picked up:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( bool value );
```

As `p` is not null, then `1` is printed.

If you need to print an actual address, then the [cast is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout), as others mention.

Answer (score 1):

Your function pointer is cast to a `bool` which is `true`, or `1` without `std::boolalpha`.

If you want to see the address you can cast it:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << std::endl;
```