# Printing time function to console produces 1

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, ctime

A couple of developers and I were wondering why:

```
std::cout<<std::time<<std::endl;
```

prints out a value of 1. What does the value represents, and why the value is of 1.

Answer to what happened: 
[How to print function pointers with cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout)

The C++ Standard specifies:

> 4.12 Boolean conversions
>
> 1 An rvalue of arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member
>   type can be converted to an rvalue of type bool.

Quote from anon:

> This is the only conversion specified for function pointers.

Edit: The answer below nicely presents the solution as to why 1 was printed rather than just any bool and explained when 1 would not occur.

Comment: Probably conversion from function pointer to `bool`.  `std::time` is not being invoked here.

Comment: Yes, we had a lot of probably(s), but would like a definite answer instead of dodging bullets when asked by learning individuals.

Comment: Answer is provided Vittorio Romeo. You forgot `()`. I'd expect it should invoke a warning at least in normal compilers.

Comment: It looks like it, thank you. What're the procedures to completing/terminating a dupe?

Comment: @dstackflow Someone will mark the question for you.

Comment: The solution selected additionally answered why 1 was exclusively selected, and was not explained in the other post, so I've chosen to alter the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) says that:

> There are no overload for pointers to non-static member, pointers to
>   volatile, or function pointers (other than the ones with signatures
>   accepted by the (10-12) overloads). Attempting to output such objects
>   invokes implicit conversion to bool, and, for any non-null pointer
>   value, the value 1 is printed (unless boolalpha was set, in which case
>   true is printed).

So you get function pointer `std::time` converted to `bool` and it is always `true` that is without `boolalpha` set output as `1`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that under some compilers/settings it is possible to issue a warning that look like this (example gcc): `warning: the address of 'time_t time(time_t*)' will never be NULL [-Waddress]`

Comment: Almost walked away without knowing that 1 was selectively chosen or when it might not be chosen. Great solution.