# C++ how to call header-only library

Tags: c++, c++17, inline, header-only

I learnt C++17 way of dealing with header-only library, by adding `inline` keyword:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct C {
    static const inline string N {"abc"};
};

int main() {
    cout << C::N << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Running above piece of code returns `abc` as expected.

However, if I tried to use the pre-C++17 style as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct C {
    static std::string& N() {
        static std::string s {"abc"};
        return s;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << C::N << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I got result of `1` rather than the expected `abc`. I'm wondering why and how to fix it?

Comment: Isn't `N` a function in the second case?

Comment: You need to call that function.

Comment: `C::N` is a function pointer, which gets converted to a `bool` for output.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is coming from the differences between your two 'N' declarations.
In the first case `static const inline string N {"abc"};` is a string variable.
In the second case `static std::string& N()` is a function.
This is why when you use `C::N` the first time it works, it is the same as using `"abc"`  in its place because it is just a string variable. This is also why it does not work as expected in the second case: `C::N` is a function not a variable in the typical sense. So to run the function you must call it by using `C::N()` which **does** output a string.

Edit: See @1201ProgramAlarm's comment on your question for the reason you get a `1` when the function isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it can be easily solved by adding a `()` after N for the 2nd case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct C {
    static std::string& N() {
        static std::string s {"abc"};
        return s;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << C::N() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```