# Why do I get integer output when I try to put "glfwSetErrorCallback" function in cout, which return non-integer value?

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm learning GLFW 3.3, and, as it's said in functions description:

> Returns the previously set callback, or NULL if no callback was set.

Source: [https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__init.html#gaff45816610d53f0b83656092a4034f40]

Now what I'm trying to do is to understand what kind of value it is. I tried to understand it as if the return value was a pointer to a function, because, as said about GLFWerrorfun type in the documentation:

> `typedef void(* GLFWerrorfun) (int, const char *)`
> This is the function pointer type for error callbacks.

Source: [https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__init.html#ga6b8a2639706d5c409fc1287e8f55e928]

Here's my code:

```
#define GLFW_DLL
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

void handleErrorCallback (int code, const char * description)
{
    // Code
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << glfwSetErrorCallback (handleErrorCallback) << std::endl;
    std::cout << glfwSetErrorCallback (NULL) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The first value written on the console is 0.
I get it as the NULL was returned because no callback was set yet.

The second value written on the console is 1, and it confuses me: how did  GLFWerrorfun return value was converted to an integer? All I see is that it's always returns '1' when the callback function was set and always '0' when it wasn't.

Comment: Because `std::cout` interprets pointers as integers. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout

Comment: I think this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout

Comment: read the [docs](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__error.html#gaa5d796c3cf7c1a7f02f845486333fb5f) to find out what it returns

Comment: @bb1950328 this document is commented in my question. Sorry, but you don't point at the answer.

Comment: @CoSalamander it's not the same document. But the answer is also in the document you linked. Read carefully what `glfwSetErrorCallback` returns. (It's "The previously set callback, or NULL if no callback was set or an error occurred.")

Comment: @bb1950328 Ok, I modified the header so it'll be more obvious that semantics of the questions description is connected to that header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glfwSetErrorCallback returns a pointer wich is interpreted as an integer.

I think this post will help:[How to print function pointers with cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout)

Comment: So, it should be enough to modify the output as:
`std::cout << ((void*) glfwSetErrorCallback (handleErrorCallback)) << std::endl;
std::cout << ((void*) glfwSetErrorCallback (NULL)) << std::endl;`