# C++ lambda function with no argument return 1

Tags: c++, lambda

I was writing simple C++ program, while using lambda function, and I got into this situation

`std::cout << [](int x = 10) -> int { return (x + 5); } << std::endl; // prints 1`

I expected, with no passing argument, this lambda function would return `15`, therefore printed result would be 15.

But above lambda function returns `1` instead. Does it mean that the lambda function just worked correctly? Is is some kind of flag value?

Comment: The Lambda is not being called and is decaying to a pointer which is printed as 1 if not null and 0 if null.  Change it to `[](int x = 10) -> int { return (x + 5); }()` to call it.

Comment: @RichardCritten Why is the pointer printing as 1 or 0 though? An ordinary `int*` pointer prints in hexadecimal (so an output of the form `0x768ab3` would make sense to me), so why do lambdas decay to Boolean when printed?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo _"...There are no overloads for pointers to non-static members, pointers to volatiles, (until C++23) or __function pointers__ (other than the ones with signatures accepted by the (11-13) overloads). Attempting to output such objects invokes __implicit conversion to bool__, and, for any non-null pointer value, the value 1 is printed (unless boolalpha was set, in which case true is printed)...."_ see __Notes__ here - [std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::operator<<](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout