# What happened when I use "class::variable" when the variable is no static?

Tags: c++, memory, compilation

I know there is something logically wrong with the code itself, but ignoring these issues, I wonder why I am getting this output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person {

public:
    Person(int age)
    {
        this->age = age;
    }
    int Person::* p = &Person::age;
    //int *p = &age;
    int age;
    int a;
};


void test01()
{
    Person p1(18);
    cout << "age of p1:" << p1.p<< endl;
}

int main()
{
    test01();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is always 1, and p's address is always eight bytes before age's address. When I check the value of p, the debugger tell me it's "&Person::age".

I don't know why this happen, I'm not very clear about the compilation process of C++ code, in fact, I want to know what is it at various points in memory.I'd appreciate it if anyone can tell me why this happen.

Comment: You may wish to read about [pointers-to-member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members) in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: `cout <<  p1.p` is equivalent to `cout <<  (p1.p ? 1 : 0)`. Since there's no operator for printing a pointer-to-member, it's converted to `bool` (`true` for non-null, `false` for null). And since the pointer is in fact non-null, `1` is printed. If you wish to access the value the pointer points to, that would be `p1.*p`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik maybe you should post that as an answer ?

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is clear. I really didn't know about pointers-to-member, and when I try it, you anwsered why every printer to member outputs 1, thank you very much! @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Please remove `using namespace std;`; it is an infamous antipattern which should not be posted on the web.

Comment: Side note: `p1.*p1.p` is the expression you may have wanted to print out.

Comment: *"I wonder why I am getting this output."* -- What output did you expect?

Comment: The reason you always get 1 is basically what is explained in [How to print function pointers with cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064692) Just read "function pointer" as "pointer, but not a pointer-to-object" (such as your pointer-to-member).